# How to set column names with DataFrame.T

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that I learned that I can "flip" with df.T but I am wondering how to add the new column names at the same time that I transpose the data frame.

My data is like this:

```
dict = {"a":[1,2,3,4],
        "b":['A','B','C','D'],
        "c":['day','night','day','day']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

   a  b      c
0  1  A    day
1  2  B  night
2  3  C    day
3  4  D    day
```

And with df.T like this:

```
df.T
     0      1    2    3
a    1      2    3    4
b    A      B    C    D
c  day  night  day  day
```

But I am trying (and failing) to have the headers change with transpose like this:

```
dfT = df.T(headers = df['b'])
dfT = df.T.columns = df['b']
```

My desired result is to have this while at the same time I transpose:

```
     A      B    C    D
a    1      2    3    4
b    A      B    C    D
c  day  night  day  day
```

Is this possible with df.T?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
dfT = df.T.rename(columns=df.b)

>>> dfT
     A      B    C    D
a    1      2    3    4
b    A      B    C    D
c  day  night  day  day
```

Answer (score 6):

### `set_index` prior to transposition

```
df.set_index('b').T

b    A      B    C    D
a    1      2    3    4
c  day  night  day  day
```

However, that moves the row.

### `drop=False`

```
df.set_index('b', drop=False).T

b    A      B    C    D
a    1      2    3    4
b    A      B    C    D
c  day  night  day  day
```

### `set_axis` after transposition.

```
df.T.set_axis(df.b, axis=1, inplace=False)

b    A      B    C    D
a    1      2    3    4
b    A      B    C    D
c  day  night  day  day
```

In the future, `Pandas.DataFrame.set_axis` will have `inplace=False` as the default argument value and this could be just

```
df.T.set_axis(df.b, 1)
```

Comment: this doesn't match the desired output exactly

Answer (score 2):

Fairly simple

```
dfT = df.T
dfT.columns = df['b'].values

     A      B    C    D
a    1      2    3    4
b    A      B    C    D
c  day  night  day  day
```

Comment: thank you for the reply! I was trying to it all at once if possible, however

Comment: yeah, I missed the 'at the same time' part of the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df.set_index(df['b']).T
```

Note: You are creating a new series equal to column b in the dataframe and not moving column 'b' into the index.

```
b    A      B    C    D
a    1      2    3    4
b    A      B    C    D
c  day  night  day  day
```

And, to remove column.name you can use:

```
df.set_index(df['b']).rename_axis(None).T
```

Output:

```
     A      B    C    D
a    1      2    3    4
b    A      B    C    D
c  day  night  day  day
```